# ROS Noetic driver for UR10e on Wifi connection?

Tags: ros-noetic, universal-robot, universal-robots

We're trying to route ROS traffic through a mobile base's wifi to a UR10e.  I think the RTDE is saturating the connection.  Are there options to slow the RTDE rate and maintain functionality with https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver?  Or has the primary interface been supported on that repo?  Are there any other viable options like trying to port over https://github.com/ros-industrial/ur_modern_driver ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems unlikely to me that RTDE is the culprit; I wouldn't expect that data to be transmitted over WiFi since the node that actually needs to interface with the UR10e will need to be running on a device that is physically connected to it. However, high volumes of sensor data (usually camera streams) can definitely throttle bandwidth.

Your best bet is likely to observe what connections are taking place over WiFi and, if possible, reduce them. You can use the `rosnode info` on each node to check what node exists on what machine. You can then move nodes such that sensor data streamed over WiFi is reduced as much as possible. You can also throttle back how frequently sensor data is published: for example, it's probably functionally identical to have a camera operate at 60 frames per second vs 30, but by choosing 30 you'll have cut the amount of data in half.